# Target WSGI script cannot be loaded as Python module (Flask) (Apache) using Python3, cannot find fix

Tags: python-3.x, apache, ubuntu, flask, mod-wsgi

Here is the error message from /var/log/apache2/error.log
I do no understand why this is not being recognized as a python module

```
mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.5.1+.

mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.5.2.

AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.5.2 configured -- resuming normal operations

AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

mod_wsgi (pid=26111): Target WSGI script '/var/www/smsblog/smsblog.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.

mod_wsgi (pid=26111): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/smsblog/smsblog.wsgi'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/var/www/smsblog/smsblog.wsgi", line 15, in <module>
 app = smsblog.config_app('smsblog')
 AttributeError: module 'smsblog.smsblog' has no attribute 'config_app'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error in my own code, it couldnt be loaded because of I did not have a config_app function in my flask app